# CoreBluetooth writeValue:forDescriptor: issue

Tags: ios5, descriptor, core-bluetooth

My CoreBluetooth application need to enable the "indication bit" in Client Characteristic Configuration descriptors. Here is what I did:

1. Start to scan
2. Start to connect to the device
3. Call `discoverServices`
4. Call `discoverCharacteristics` inside the callback

   -(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error
5. Call `discoverDescriptorsForCharacteristic` inside callback

   -(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error
6. Inside callback

   -(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverDescriptorsForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error

I called:

```
        if ( [[descriptor.UUID representativeString] isEqualToString:@"2902" ] )
        {
            const unsigned char raw_data[] = {0x02};
            NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithBytes: raw_data length: 2];
            [self.cBCP writeValue:myData forDescriptor:descriptor];
        }
```

But My app crashes in `writeVale`: . The error message in console is :

> Cannot write Client Characteristic Configuration descriptors using
>   this method!

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: I'm wondering if there is any sample code using writeVale:forDescriptor.

Comment: Actually my solution is not use writeValue:forDescriptor.

Comment: Can you explain how you how to enable indication without using writeValue:forDescriptor?  I'm stuck at the same place...

Comment: Did you get any solution here ?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty old question, but since it wasn't answered, seems like if the method `setNotifyValue(_:for:)` will handle that for you, it depends on the charcateristics properties below:

- Notify only: Notifications will be enabled.
- Indicate only: Indications will be enabled.
- Indicate & Notify: ONLY Notifications will be enabled.

So if you need to enable indications, the characteristic must only have the indicate property, and notify should be removed.

I guess the main reasoning behind that is indications are much slower, so iOS will always prefer the fastest possible option unless it's a requirement to indicate.

[Read more on the Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheral/1518949-setnotifyvalue)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot use the writeValue:forDescriptor: method to write the value of a Client Configuration Descriptor (UUID = 2902) as you did.

Instead, you should use the setNotifyValue:forCharacteristic: method of the CBPeripheral class to configure client indications or notifications of a characteristic’s value on a server.